# Writing to BigQuery via local DataFlow job

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a DataFlow pipeline set up locally on my machine. It takes a sample new line delimited file full of JSON objects, does its thing, formats the end result in `TableRow`. When it is time to write to BigQuery, I don't know how to authenticate. I couldn't find anything in Dataflow's documentation or examples where one writes to BigQuery using a local pipeline. If possible I would like to know how to do it. In my mind it should be something like either:

```
...
session_windowed_items.apply(ParDo.of(new FormatAsTableRowFn()))
      .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
      .withCredentials/Token(SOME_TOKEN)  // <- This line
      .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
      .to("project:db.table"));
...
```

or

```
...
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
options.setGoogleCloudCredentials/Token(SOME_TOKEN)  // <- This line
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach is the right one. It will looks something like this:

```java
GcpOptions gcpOptions = options.as(GcpOptions.class);
gcpOptions.setGcpCredential(...);
gcpOptions.setProject(...);
// etc
```

The idiom of `options.as(SomeSpecificOptions.class)` is worth remembering.

You'll want to read over [GcpOptions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/GcpOptions) to see the methods available.